# Yum file conflicts due to my mistake. How do I fix?

Tags: rhel, yum

I did something stupid.  I simply `scp`ed my *rpmforge* repo files from another (working) machine on to my dev box, and ran `yum update`.  This yielded:

```
root@dev07 /etc/yum.repos.d # yum update
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
rpmforge                                                                                                                                                                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00     
rpmforge/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                              | 2.7 MB     00:01     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package htop.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package htop.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6.rf will be an update
---> Package libewf.x86_64 0:20100226-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package libewf.x86_64 0:20100226-1.el6.rf will be an update
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.021-136.el6 will be updated
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.052-1.el6.rf will be an update
---> Package testdisk.x86_64 0:6.14-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package testdisk.x86_64 0:6.14-1.el6.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libreiserfs-0.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: testdisk-6.14-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libntfs-3g.so.84()(64bit) for package: testdisk-6.14-1.el6.rf.x86_64
---> Package xclip.x86_64 0:0.12-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package xclip.x86_64 0:0.12-1.el6.rf will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fuse-ntfs-3g.x86_64 0:2013.1.13-2.el6.rf will be installed
---> Package progsreiserfs.x86_64 0:0.3.0.4-1.2.el6.rf will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                      Arch                                        Version                                                   Repository                                     Size
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 htop                                                         x86_64                                      1.0.3-1.el6.rf                                            rpmforge                                       87 k
 libewf                                                       x86_64                                      20100226-1.el6.rf                                         rpmforge                                      343 k
 perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2                                      x86_64                                      2.052-1.el6.rf                                            rpmforge                                      104 k
 testdisk                                                     x86_64                                      6.14-1.el6.rf                                             rpmforge                                      451 k
 xclip                                                        x86_64                                      0.12-1.el6.rf                                             rpmforge                                       27 k
Installing for dependencies:
 fuse-ntfs-3g                                                 x86_64                                      2013.1.13-2.el6.rf                                        rpmforge                                      483 k
 progsreiserfs                                                x86_64                                      0.3.0.4-1.2.el6.rf                                        rpmforge                                      119 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       5 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.6 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/7): fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                 | 483 kB     00:00     
(2/7): htop-1.0.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                             |  87 kB     00:00     
(3/7): libewf-20100226-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                        | 343 kB     00:00     
(4/7): perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.052-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                          | 104 kB     00:00     
(5/7): progsreiserfs-0.3.0.4-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                | 119 kB     00:00     
(6/7): testdisk-6.14-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                          | 451 kB     00:00     
(7/7): xclip-0.12-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                             |  27 kB     00:00     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                                    873 kB/s | 1.6 MB     00:01     
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
```

Oops.  I didn't [follow the directions](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge).  So I deleted the `*rpmforge*` files from `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, and started over the correct way.  Which all went fine until I tried another `yum update`:

```
[snip]
Transaction Check Error:
  file /sbin/mount.lowntfs-3g from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
  file /sbin/mount.ntfs from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
  file /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/ntfs-3g from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/ntfsmount from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.8.gz from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.probe.8.gz from install of fuse-ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-2.el6.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

root@dev07 /etc/yum.repos.d #
```

I suppose I could just delete those files, but I want to be sure that by getting a bigger hammer, I'm not just breaking my system in to smaller pieces first.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing `ntfs-3g-2:2011.4.12-5.el6.x86_64` package by:

> yum remove ntfs-3g

See which packages depends on this package. If there is only one package appeared in list of removing package by yum, you can confidently remove this package. (**Note:** Don't press 'Y' for removing packages if you don't know which are they.)

After this go for `yum update`.

Comment: This turned out to be the secret sauce, although I did need to employ some `clean all` and `distro-sync` actions from another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tidy up the `yum` cache directory:

```
# yum clean all
```

Then, try downgrading the package with:

```
# yum downgrade fuse-ntfs-3g
```

From the man page:

```
   downgrade
          Will try and downgrade a package from the version currently
          installed to the previously highest version (or the specified
          version).  The depsolver will not necessarily work, but if you
          specify all the packages it should work (thus, all the simple
          cases will work). Also this does not work for "installonly"
          packages, like Kernels. downgrade operates on groups, files,
          provides, filelists and rpm files just like the "install"
          command.
```

Or, to bring the whole system to a known state (with no `rpmforge` packages):

```
# yum distro-sync
```

Again, from the man page:

```
   distribution-synchronization or distro-sync
          Synchronizes the installed package set with the latest
          packages available, this is done by either obsoleting,
          upgrading or downgrading as appropriate. This will "normally"
          do the same thing as the upgrade command however if you have
          the package FOO installed at version 4, and the latest
          available is only version 3, then this command will downgrade
          FOO to version 3.
```